# alert javascript generated div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've generated some divs with .append() method.

Code looks like that:

```
$("#someDiv").prepend("<div id='someId' class='myClass'></div>"):
$("#someDiv").prepend("<div id='someId2' class='myClass'></div>"):
```

that works great, now, i want to use that divs id's.

i'm trying to do it this way:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

but, it does not work, help me please.

Comment: Did you put your code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ...});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements are dynamically generated, you probably need to delegate the event to an element that actually exists when binding the handler, something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#someDiv").on("click", ".myClass", function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

And you'll need to replace the colon on the end of you're prepends with a semicolon to make those work.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XZVgT/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe because you are binding the click event to "myClass" before actually adding the divs. Try placing the click event code after the code for adding new divs like this

```
$("#someDiv").prepend("<div id='someId' class='myClass'></div>"):
$("#someDiv").prepend("<div id='someId2' class='myClass'></div>"):

$(".myClass").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```